# Python Why thread.Condition.wait take so long?

Tags: python, multithreading

I was using CPython ,and found out that the wait() method of thread.Condition is very inefficient .

```
import datetime
import threading

cond = threading.Condition()
start = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(100):
    with cond:
        if cond.wait(timeout=0.0001):
            pass
print((datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()/100)
```

It seems like cond.wait will always takes at least 0.01 second to proceed .
Even if I set timeout as 0.0001 .
I know GIL is inefficient ,but does it really takes that long ?

Comment: I ran your code but I didn't get a result supporting your hypothesis that wait takes at least 0.01secs to release the condition. Your code runs under 0.003secs for me. What version of Python are you running this on?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: @OluwafemiSule But 0.003sec is still 30 times longer than 0.0001sec .I still don't get what's happening here ? Is 0.003sec quite normal for aquiring a _thread.lock ?

Comment: The OS is heavily involved here, and differences from one machine to another (and to the same machine under various loading conditions) are to be expected.  You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875178/how-long-is-the-time-frame-between-context-switches-on-windows.  I'm not sure there is a good reason to attribute this "inefficiency" to Python or its GIL.

Comment: It was 0.0003secs I missed a zero there :)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you .Are you using CPython too ?

Comment: Yeah running `python3 -c "import platform;print(platform.python_implementation())"` gives CPython